# Starting an animation when it is scrolled into view

Tags: javascript, css

I have 2 `<hr>` elements that are animated and move into close to each other. I want the animation to take place once the `<hr>` elements are in the viewport, instead of occurring right when the page is loaded. I have included my JavaScript code but this code didn't work; not sure if I'm using the right event.

```js
'use strict';

const linebreak = document.querySelector('#hero--one');
const symbolContainer = document.querySelector('.header__container-symbol')

linebreak.addEventListener('scroll', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  const containerCoords = symbolContainer.getBoundingClientRect();

  symbolContainer.scrollIntoView({
    behavior: 'smooth'
  });
  linebreak.classList.remove('hidden');


})
```

```css
/* Lines and Diamond above title */

.header__container-symbol {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
  background-color: rgba(25, 25, 25, 1);
}

.span-D {
  align-self: center;
}

.hr-symbol {
  width: 60rem;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 0.3rem;
  background-color: #eee;
}

#hero--one {
  margin-right: 3px;
  animation: moveInLeftHr;
  animation-duration: 2s;
}

#symbol {
  font-size: 3rem;
}

#hero--two {
  margin-left: 3px;
  animation: moveInRightHr;
  animation-duration: 2s;
}

#symbol {
  color: #eee;
  margin-right: 2rem;
  margin-left: 2rem;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}


/* End Diamon and Lines above title */


/* KeyFrames Animations */

@keyframes moveInLeftHr {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateX(-100px);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translate(0);
  }
}

@keyframes moveInRightHr {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateX(100px);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translate(0);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="header__container-symbol">
  <span class="span-D"><hr  class="hidden hr-symbol" id="hero--one"/></span>
  <span id="symbol"> &#11033; </span>
  <span class="span-D"><hr class="hidden hr-symbol" id="hero--two"/></span>
</div>
```

Comment: It’s about time we avoid using scroll event listeners, when IntersectionObserver can be used instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [Intersection Observer API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API) to detect when the element intersects with the viewport.

The `threshold` option is set to `1`, meaning it will check for when the element is fully within the viewport.

A test `div` has been inserted at the top of the html to demonstrate the behavior.

```js
'use strict';

const linebreak1 = document.querySelector('#hero--one');
const linebreak2 = document.querySelector('#hero--two');
const symbolContainer = document.querySelector('.header__container-symbol')

const observer = new IntersectionObserver((entries, observer) => {
  if (!entries[0].isIntersecting) return;
  linebreak1.classList.remove('hidden');
  linebreak2.classList.remove('hidden');
}, { threshold: 1 });

observer.observe(symbolContainer);
```

```css
/* Lines and Diamond above title */

.header__container-symbol {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
  background-color: rgba(25, 25, 25, 1);
}

.span-D {
  align-self: center;
}

.hr-symbol {
  width: 60rem;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 0.3rem;
  background-color: #eee;
}

#hero--one {
  margin-right: 3px;
  animation: moveInLeftHr;
  animation-duration: 2s;
}

#symbol {
  font-size: 3rem;
}

#hero--two {
  margin-left: 3px;
  animation: moveInRightHr;
  animation-duration: 2s;
}

#symbol {
  color: #eee;
  margin-right: 2rem;
  margin-left: 2rem;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}


/* End Diamon and Lines above title */


/* KeyFrames Animations */

@keyframes moveInLeftHr {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateX(-100px);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translate(0);
  }
}

@keyframes moveInRightHr {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateX(100px);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translate(0);
  }
}
```

```html
<div style="height: 500px;"></div>

<div class="header__container-symbol">
  <span class="span-D"><hr  class="hidden hr-symbol" id="hero--one"/></span>
  <span id="symbol"> &#11033; </span>
  <span class="span-D"><hr class="hidden hr-symbol" id="hero--two"/></span>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you @skara9. I am going to read up on the IntersectionObserver. I am fairly new to JavaScript and was unaware of this, but this worked exactly how I wanted it to. Thanks.